# The limit of a Expected Value of a Function of Sequence of Rvs

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

The question states:

> Show $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] = g(c)$$
>   Where $X_n$ is a sequence of Random Variables. We discerned that $g(X_n) \rightarrow g(c)$ in probability, where $g$ is a continuous and bounded function, and also uniformly continuous on $[c-\delta, c+\delta]$.  Also $X_n \rightarrow c$ in probability.
>   The hint says, to rewrite $\mathbb{E}[g(X_n)-g(c)]$ as:
>   $$\mathbb{E}[(g(X_n) - g(c))\mathbb{1}_{|g(X_n)-g(c)| \leq \epsilon}] + \mathbb{E}[(g(X_n) - g(c))\mathbb{1}_{|g(X_n)-g(c)| > \epsilon}]$$for all  $\epsilon>0$.

The way I thought about it is if $|g(X_n) - g(c)| > \epsilon$, then we know by convergence in probability that $$\mathbb{P}(|g(X_n) - g(c)| > \epsilon) = 0, n \rightarrow \infty$$

Also, we know that $|g(X_n) - g(c)| \leq \epsilon$, which we can show by limit definition that the limit of $g(X_n)$ is $g(c)$.

Thus the expectation must be $0$, thus by linearity of Expectation we get that:

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_n)-g(c)] = \mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] - \mathbb{E}[g(c)] = 0$$

Thus $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] = g(c)$$

But I don't think this is correct. If someone had any tips, it would be appreciated.

Comment: See what. The convergence in mean is implied from the convergence in measure, while there is majorant (i.e. the random variable with finite mean). So you should try to find this kind of function. The uniform boundedness should help.

Comment: Portmanteau theorem?

Comment: I know about the Portmanteau Theorem but I'm just looking for a way to do it similar to the method approached above.